# Is there a java system property for the C: drive (or unix equivalent)?

Tags: java, ant, build, system

I have an ant build I'm trying to customize so that the files being built are deployed outside of my project folder.

The Java System properties give me access to ${user.home} but I need to be higher "Machintosh HD/Applications" to be exact.

How can I point ant to a directory higher than user.home?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just use forward slashes (Unix style) and just start your paths with `/`:

```
<property name="root.dir" location="/"/>
```

and it will resolve the root of the default drive appropriate to your OS platform (e.g. `C:\` on Windows  and `/` on Unix).

```
<property name="tmp.dir" location="/tmp"/>
```

will resolve to `C:\tmp` or `/tmp`, depending on your platform.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`getParent()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getParent%28%29)

```
File f = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"));
f.getParent();//this would return the parent of user home which you need.
```

On your update:

```
You can use [File.listRoots()][2]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try have a look on [`File.listRoots()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listRoots%28%29). Combining with [ANT java task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html) might get the desired result.

Comment: `Java System properties give me access to ${user.home} but I need to be higher "Machintosh HD/Applications" to be exact.` @John you need root or the direct above dir of user.home ?>

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just use `${user.home}/../`?

Answer (score 1):

Another interesting class is FileSystemView. It contains OS-Specific information about special files, such as the Desktop item or the "my Computer" node:

```
    final javax.swing.filechooser.FileSystemView fileSystemView = javax.swing.filechooser.FileSystemView.getFileSystemView();
    File[] roots=fileSystemView.getRoots();
```

you can  use this class for checking whether a file is a Drive node or a Floppy disk node, and furthermore using isTraversable you can check for e.g. empty CD-ROM drives, i.e. existing roots for which File.listFiles() would fail.

Answer (score 0):

What about defining your own variable? 
See [here](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/docbook/setup/ant.variables.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use [`File.listRoots()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listRoots%28%29)

> List the available filesystem roots.
>
> A particular Java platform may support
> zero or more hierarchically-organized
> file systems. Each file system has a
> root directory from which all other
> files in that file system can be
> reached. Windows platforms, for
> example, have a root directory for
> each active drive; UNIX platforms have
> a single root directory, namely "/".
>
> The set of available filesystem roots
> is affected by various system-level
> operations such as the insertion or
> ejection of removable media and the
> disconnecting or unmounting of
> physical or virtual disk drives.

Comment: I think he is trying to reference it from ANT ... so it would be worth to mention ANT java task as well.

Comment: which you did, so +1 to you :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the drive-listing code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(File drive:File.listRoots())
        System.out.println(drive.getPath());
}
```